# Aviso de "Questão muito ativa" no SO em Português não está traduzido

Tags: bug, status-pronto, localização

O menu de ordenação de respostas foi [recentemente traduzido](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377345/the-new-answer-sorting-menu-appears-in-english-even-on-language-specific-sites#comment1263911_378388). Em face disso a mensagem de "Questão muito ativa" ficou sem tradução no SOpt ([postagem de exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43193)):

[image]

No [SO em Espanhol](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/42977) já está traduzida:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Identificamos o problema e fizemos a tradução.**

Foi identificado que temos duas *strings* para esta situação, uma provavelmente para usuários com menor pontuação neste site (provavelmente depende do privilégio de proteger ou desproteger perguntas).

Aparentemente não tem uma relação direta com o novo menu, mas de qualquer forma precisava ser traduzida.

Uma delas já estava traduzida:

[image: Screenshot of already translated banner]

Mas faltava esta outra, com um pouco mais de informação:

[image: Screenshot of untranslated banner]

Comment: [The notice has been translated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMZD8.png) :)

Comment: @Justin Great! Question tags updated ;)